# Jquery with large/numerous items in selector cause error on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-selectors

I am trying to run a selector that has a large number of element ids to match but in IE8 i keep getting the error: object doesnt support this property or method.

The jquery is like this:

```
var elements = $('#182,#183,#184,#185,#211,#212,#213,#214,#220,#221,
#222,#223,#225,#226,#227,#228,#234,#241,#242,#243,#244,
#245,#246,#247,#248,#250,#251,#252,#253,#256,#257,#258,#259,#260');
```

The actual query is actually longer and the ids are not sequential.
I have broken up the list into smaller parts and run each part separately. 
All of the smaller selectors run fine.

I was wondering if there is a way i could use one selector?

As Requested here is an example of the markup but there is hundreds of rows in reality:

```
<table id="ListTable">
<tbody>
<tr id="1" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="2" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="3" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="4" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="95" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="5" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="6" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="7" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="8" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="9" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="10" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="11" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="82" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="83" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tr id="84" style="display: none;"></tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you show your HTML markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put a class on each of those elements with ids(btw don't use ids with just numbers. make them a bit more descriptive and just parse them with substring) and call that class instead so you'll get an array of those elements:

```
$(".classname")
```

say you wanted to select:

```
<input id="#example_182" class="example" />
<input id="#example_125" class="example" />
<input id="#example_252" class="example" />
<input id="#example_183" class="example" />
<input id="#example_345" class="example" />
<input id="#example_456" class="example" />
```

you can then select them all using:

```
$(".example")
```

then if you wanted to get their ids loop through example and then do a substring

```
$(".example").each(function(ex) {
   myid = $(this).attr("id").substring(8)
})
```

*note, you better check the documentation for each, im not actually sure that's the syntax

Comment: Thanks @corroded but that does not do what I need directly, the list of ids are the ids of rows in a table. I want to show/hide a number of rows based on a value from a select element. Lets say the user selects the option group1 from a select element I then want to hide all the ids related to that group (which i store in a javascript array). I build the selector above and then hide the list. I may add a class to each row element that identifies the goup its related to. which will probably get around the issue. However i just wanted to see if anyone knew away around this limitation?

Comment: it was just an exmaple since i didn't know which kind of elements you needed the classes and ids. but wasn't my suggestion correct for you?

Comment: I decided to follow @corroded lead and add classes to the divs that represent the groups rows are related to eachother.